# How to load module faster in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, module, air, flash-builder

I am currently working on a modular application which contains lots of modules and i am loading the modules using ModuleLoader which load the modules faster that are contains less number of visual components,But the modules which contains lots of visual components then it takes lots of time to load the module.For example i have created a periodic table which contains all the elements and each element is a custom component when i load the module it is taking almost five seconds to load and it freezes the main application.I have to load the same module for multiple times in my application which makes the application very slow.

Is it possible to load the module faster or preload the module so it can be added to the stage faster or any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you please tell why do you need to load the same module several times? According to the ModuleLoader documentation, there is a contract your module must support: _This contract dictates that the child SWF file implements IFlexModuleFactory and that the factory implemented can be used to create multiple instances of the child class as needed._ So, as I understand, once the module is loaded, you can just create another instance when you need.

Comment: Regarding the question about preloading resources. It's a common practice to create some kind of preloader. You can define some resource manifest and create a loading queue to manage loading of all required resources. While the resources are loading you can show some progress bar or whatever you like. You can implement this queue by yourself using ModuleLoader or Loader, the other option is to take some 3rd party library, for example the greensock loader: https://greensock.com/LoaderMax-AS3

Comment: My application is like Microsoft Powerpoint which contains different slides so a user can add multiple widgets in it and save it in some format and i can reload the document when ever i want.